# Density of Maximum brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Why is it that for $M(t):=\max\limits_{0\leq s\leq t}B(s)$
$$P(M(t)\geq a) = 2P(B(t)\geq a)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{a/\sqrt{\sigma^2t}}^{\infty}e^{-y^2/2}dy, \ a \geq 0$$
Doesn't result in:
$$f_{M(t)}(a)=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2t}}e^{-a^2/2\sigma^2t}$$
when differentiating with respect to $a$?

Comment: Are you interested in the density of $M(t)$? In that case, you need to differentiate $Pr(M(t)<a)$ rather than $Pr(M(t)\geq a)$

Comment: I think I see where I went wrong.  When I did that I didn't take into account $a>0$ so the new integral goes over $2-2\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-a/\sqrt{\sigma^2t}}e^{-y^2/2}dy$ and then the negative cancels